# Get data from two arrays in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

how can I get specific data from two arrays in a `foreach` of the array below?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeGRQ.png)

I want to get `GaNivelAcesso.descricao` and `GaUsuario.usuario`, I didn't get it yet, because when I'm going to iterate in the array it gives error

> My GaNivelUsuarioController index:

```
public function index(){
    $query = $this->GaNivelUsuario->find('all')->contain(['GaUsuario', 'GaNivelAcesso']);
    $this->set('query', $query);
    $gaNivelUsuario = $this->paginate($this->GaNivelUsuario);
    $this->set(compact('gaNivelUsuario'));
}
```

Comment: What does your view code look like, where you try to iterate it, and what error do you get?

Comment: Please share your view code